# Combine two foreach into one

Tags: php

how can I combine these 2 foreach into 1?

```
 <?PHP
    $directory = "images/uploads/fexperience/";
    $images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");
    $imagespng = glob($directory . "*.png");
    foreach($images as $image)
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
            echo '<li><a href="frmExcludeImage.php?imagename='.$image.'"><img src="'.$image.'" width="150" height="70" /></a></li>';
        } else{
            echo '<li><a href="'.$image.'" style="background-image:url('.$image.')" ><img src="'.$image.'" width="150" height="70" /></a></li>';
        }
    }
    echo "<br>";
    foreach($imagespng as $imagepng)
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
            echo '<li><a href="frmExcludeImage.php?imagename='.$image.'"><img src="'.$image.'" width="150" height="70" /></a></li>';
        } else{
            echo '<li><a href="'.$image.'" style="background-image:url('.$image.')" ><img src="'.$image.'" width="150" height="70" /></a></li>';
        }
    }
?>
```

I've tried a lot but its not working when I do and I don't know why. It just stop working. How can I merge this 2 foreach as 1? Please

Comment: So you want to loop through both arrays at the same time?

Comment: `glob()` returns a simple array, so just merge the two arrays: `$images = array_merge(glob($directory . "*.jpg"), glob($directory . "*.png"));`.... then you only have one array to loop over

Comment: @MarkBaker provide that as answer so I can upvote

Comment: It feels a bit like rep-w**ring for something so simple, but.... see below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[glob()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) returns a simple array, so just merge the two arrays, and then you only have one array to loop over

```
$directory = "images/uploads/fexperience/";
$images = array_merge(
    glob($directory . "*.jpg"),
    glob($directory . "*.png")
);

foreach($images as $image) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
        echo '<li><a href="frmExcludeImage.php?imagename='.$image.'"><img src="'.$image.'" width="150" height="70" /></a></li>';
    } else{
        echo '<li><a href="'.$image.'" style="background-image:url('.$image.')" ><img src="'.$image.'" width="150" height="70" /></a></li>';
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to be a really smart, you don't even need two globs, but can search for both `jpg` and `png` in a single glob():

```
$images = glob($directory . "*.{jpg,png}",  GLOB_BRACE);
```

Comment: It is doing <br> between images, look this bemestarservice.com.br/experience at the footer

Comment: @PampulhaTech that wasnt your initial question.

Comment: @PampulhaTech - Sorry, yes.... I forgot that you need the `GLOB_BRACE` flag if you want to combine both masks into a single glob statement.... edited accordingly

Answer (score 1):

```
    $directory = "images/uploads/fexperience/";
    $images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");
    $imagespng = glob($directory . "*.png");
    forEachLoop($images);
    forEachLoop($imagespng);

    function forEachLoop($images) {
        foreach($images as $image)
        {
            if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
                echo '<li><a href="frmExcludeImage.php?imagename='.$image.'"><img src="'.$image.'" width="150" height="70" /></a></li>';
            } else{
                echo '<li><a href="'.$image.'" style="background-image:url('.$image.')" ><img src="'.$image.'" width="150" height="70" /></a></li>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is doing <br> between images, look this http://bemestarservice.com.br/experience
at the footer